# BottomNavigation view selected item's label is not changed

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement simple BottomNavigationView. Fragments run correctly according to item clicked but  setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener seems not to be invoked for labels in my BottomNavigationView. For example attribute app:labelVisiilityMode=selected does not work andr still selects first item no matter what item is chosen. This is my code:

```
    private void configureBottoNavigationView() {

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
        Bundle args;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_item1:
                fragment = new FragmentList();
                args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("number_of_cols", prefList);
                args.putInt("b_nav_height", bottomNavViewHeight);
                if (position != 0)
                    args.putInt("position", position);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                break;


            case R.id.action_item2:
                fragment = new FragmentFav();
                args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("number_of_cols", prefList);
                args.putInt("b_nav_height", bottomNavViewHeight);
                if (position != 0)
                    args.putInt("position", position);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                break;

            case R.id.action_item3:
                fragment = new FragmentSearch();
                args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("number_of_cols", prefList);
                args.putInt("b_nav_height", bottomNavViewHeight);
                if (position != 0)
                    args.putInt("position", position);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

and my layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="00dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?attr/myBackgroundColor"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_items"
            app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@color/colorAccent"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"/>

    </FrameLayout>
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you explain better? What does it mean *Fragments run correctly*?

Comment: As you can see this app is fragments based and every time I choose one of a few options from BottomNavView proper fragment is invoked. The problem was just with items. They didin't indicate which item was clicked but now the problem is solved.

Comment: @color/bottom_nav_color is a color or a selector?

Comment: It's a selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` should return true.

Answer (score 0):

I think,You are using wrong id when you replace the fragment.

```
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
```

I did't find any id which name **content_frame** in your xml file. So, you can use **frame_layout** instead of content_frame.

```
  ft.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
```

Comment: Thanks for interest in my problem but this is something other